# How to remove red icon with minus sign

Tags: wine

I tried to remove the red icon with minus sign but I am getting errors. What should I do to fix it?

[image]

I tried to clean and auto remove and update and upgrade, but it did not work. This is what I tried but it dint worked out for me

[image]

[image]

What should i do to fix it ?

Comment: Please copy/paste text instead of linking to screenshots of text. One of your unlabeled images clearly shows the problem, and suggests a solution...but I can't copy text from an image to show you.

Comment: `apt-cache policy python3-minimal` please add this to your question.